# Default installation permissions in managed package

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv

I have created a managed package version that somehow defaults on installation to "Install for Admins Only". In previous versions of this package, it would default to "Install for All Users". How can I change my new managed package to default to "Install for All Users"? I don't see it as part of the "Package Components" or "Version Detail" on the detail page for the version of the managed package, and I don't see any other sections on the detail page.
[image: This is what I want it to show on installation:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the listing of the app itself - under Partner Community > Published Packages > Listings > (listing of your specific app) > App > "How should customers install your app?"